# Why is this select statement not returning what I've provided?

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables in my SQL Server I am wondering why is my select statement not working or giving the result with my condition in the where clause. I learned back there to use this kind of method..

```
Subject table
SubjectID      CourseCode
   6            SubjectA
   7            SubjectB
   8            SubjectC

Schedule table
ScheduleID     Room
   15          Room1
   16          Room2
   17          Room3

AssignSchedule table
AssignScheduleID       ScheduleID       SubjectID
    14                     15               6
    15                     16               7
```

I want to get the room of the subject SubjectA. In order to get that I came up with this select statement query

```
Select Subject.CourseCode, 
Schedule.Room from Subject, 
Schedule, AssignSchedule 
where 
AssignSchedule.ScheduleID = (Select Schedule.Schedule.ID 
from Schedule where Room = 'Room1') 
AND AssignSchedule.SubjectID = (Select Subject.SubjectID from Subject where CourseCode = 'SubjectA');
```

What happens is like this

```
CourseCode      Room

  SubjectA      Room1
  SubjectB      Room1
  SubjectC      Room1
  SubjectA      Room2
  SubjectB      Room2
  SubjectC      Room2
  SubjectA      Room3
  SubjectB      Room3
  SubjectC      Room3
```

My expected output would be like this

```
CourseCode     Room
SubjectA       Room1
```

What is wrong? Help guys..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WHERE clause returns the desired single row AssignSchedule but you have no correlation between that row and the outer Subject and Schedule tables so you get a Cartesian product of all Subject and Schedule combinations.  You could add the outer table correlations to your existing query to get the desired result:

```
SELECT  Subject.CourseCode
      , Schedule.Room
FROM    Subject
      , Schedule
      , AssignSchedule
WHERE   AssignSchedule.ScheduleID = ( SELECT    Schedule.ScheduleID
                                      FROM      Schedule
                                      WHERE     Room = 'Room1'
                                    )
        AND AssignSchedule.SubjectID = ( SELECT Subject.SubjectID
                                         FROM   Subject
                                         WHERE  CourseCode = 'SubjectA'
                                       )
        AND AssignSchedule.ScheduleID = Schedule.ScheduleID
        AND AssignSchedule.SubjectID = Subject.SubjectID;
```

A better approach would be use simple equality predicates instead in the ugly subqueries.  Below are examples using the old ANSI SQL-89 syntax you've been using as well as the ANSI SQL-92 equivalent.  I suggest the latter as it helps avoid missing join predicates.

```
SELECT  Subject.CourseCode
      , Schedule.Room
FROM    Subject
      , Schedule
      , AssignSchedule
WHERE
            AssignSchedule.ScheduleID = Schedule.ScheduleID
        AND AssignSchedule.SubjectID = Subject.SubjectID
        AND Schedule.Room = 'Room1'
        AND Subject.CourseCode = 'SubjectA';

SELECT  Subject.CourseCode
      , Schedule.Room
FROM    Subject
JOIN AssignSchedule ON AssignSchedule.SubjectID = Subject.SubjectID
JOIN Schedule ON AssignSchedule.ScheduleID = Schedule.ScheduleID
WHERE   
        Schedule.Room = 'Room1'
    AND Subject.CourseCode = 'SubjectA';
```

Comment: I didn't know that I had to add the outer table correlations! Wow! I forgot the use of join but it is must simple and organized. Should the outer correlations really needed when performing queries with single/multiple table/s? Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3323654, the concept of outer correlation applies only when multiple tables are involved (including the same table specified multiple times). In the context of the outer `FROM` clause, the rows in the tables are usually related to one another such that relationship needs to be specified in `ON` or `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Ohh I see.. Thank you again for this one!